# How to customize Firefox (57) menu?

Tags: firefox

To reach full browser history in Firefox 57 I have to do four clicks:

<kbd>Menu</kbd> -> <kbd>Library</kbd> -> <kbd>History</kbd> -> <kbd>Show All History</kbd>
*(and while the first three are in the upper part of the screen, the last one is in the lowest bottom which makes the whole thing even more annoying)*

Is there a way to move "Show All History" item (or at least "History") to the main menu?

I don't want to have this item on the toolbar or install an add-on for customizing the main menu. A little tweak in `about:config` page or editing a xml-layout-resource (if there are any) is what I'm looking for. If it's not possible to do it this or similar way, I'll live with the default behavior.

*There is an article about [Customizing Firefox controls, buttons and toolbars](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-firefox-controls-buttons-and-toolbars) but despite its title it doesn't work for menus, only for toolbars.*

Comment: What is wrong with <ctrl><shift><h>? ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill Nothing wrong! I just didn't found hotkeys/shortcut in the Options %)

Comment: @DavidPostill Now they moved them to Help!..

Comment: <alt> > History > Show all history **tells you what the shortcut is**!

Comment: @DavidPostill Oh, that's good, thank you. I wondered why in the menu shortcuts are shown for some items but not shown for others.

Comment: No idea. Want me to write up an answer?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a way to move "Show All History" item (or at least "History") to the main menu?

> I don't want to have this item on the toolbar or install an add-on for customizing the main menu.

It's already on the main menu:

<kbd>alt</kbd>  (to open the menu) > History > Show all history (or <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>)

This also shows the direct shortcut, which is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>